# MySQL Group By Issue

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I'm having some issues with the group by clause changes in MySQL 5.7. I keep getting an error indicating that I need to fix some queries to allow it to run correctly. I have followed a few different things but the only thing I found that works is by running the following queries on the server:

```
set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
set session sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Doing this gets rid of the errors and allows my app to run.

I did try adding:

```
sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

into the `/etc/mysql/my.cfg` however this caused some issues because auto increment numbers were no longer being generated, so all inserts failed.

This is now happening on a number of servers and it is painful to keep running queries if any of them restart.

Is anyone able to help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MySQL 5.7 documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html)

> To set the SQL mode at server startup, use the `--sql-mode="modes"` option on the command line, or `sql-mode="modes"` in an option file such as my.cnf (Unix operating systems) or my.ini (Windows). modes is a list of different modes separated by commas. To clear the SQL mode explicitly, set it to an empty string using --sql-mode="" on the command line, or sql-mode="" in an option file.

Include the quotes in your `my.cnf`.

Comment: Brilliant thanks, the guide I had read showed the `sql-mode` written as `sql_mode` without the quotes which is why it was not working as expected.